# How reliable is Reachability and should I take further precautions?

Tags: ios, reachability

A little vague in the title, but I want to know what others are doing about this. I wonder:

1. If you use Reachability, do you perform any additional checks or are
   you fully confident that the notifications will take care of
   everything?
2. Has anyone had any issues with their WiFi working, but
   Reachability returning false despite that there's an active connection? (I haven't myself, but have read about it somewhere).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Most API calls have a NSError argument you can leverage to get the error as well, if that is necessary

Comment: Reachability is reliable, just don't use it for one-off notifications to the user, it'll generate a ton of notifications banners!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it, and have not had any issue with reliability of detecting WiFi connectivity.  It has worked fine for me when used properly.

Comment: Hi thanks. I've been using it successfully over the past few days without a hitch; is there anything in particular you would consider 'improper' when implementing it?

Comment: Well, if you don't instantiate the check properly.  Follow Apple's example and you will be fine.